# How to add images on ActionBar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to make a action bar in android on which i want to add three Image buttons. But i don't know how to add image buttons on action bar i have no idea about it. I want to add one image button on left side of action bar and one image button on right side and one image view in center. I don't know how to make it possible.

Comment: you can use toolbar as layout and put your imageButton inside it to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using toolbar, then you can do like this.

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: This showing error in my ViewpagerAdapter  `Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
`

Comment: Include these two also.
.
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
.
PS. I'm using Studio 3.0 RC 1

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. You can add an xml whith a menu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

and then inflate it in the OnCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

or to use a Toolbar in your layout like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```